# Scaling consumers @StreamListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We're using spring cloud to serve asynchronous tasks. I wonder if there is any way to scale listeners set up by `@StreamListener`? The goal is to have multiple workers within one application instance.

I read about `spring.cloud.stream.instancecount`, but I don't want to replicate whole application, only increase workers count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that via `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency` consumer property. [Here is more info](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RC1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_common_binding_properties)

Comment: If you are using the Kafka binder, you need at least an many partitions as `concurrency` since you can only have one consumer per partition.

Comment: What if I don't have so much partitions? And just want to increase workers. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Works! I had to change `springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.M1'` to `springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.RELEASE'`